# Wordpress ul dropdown menu: display only some li sub items

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I created a dropdown menu for my Wordpress website with this PHP statement:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&sort_column=menu_order'); ?>
</ul>
```

In this jsfiddle you can find the HTML and CSS code: http://jsfiddle.net/N5H4c/

I only want to display the subpages of 'Menu item One' and not those of 'Menu item Three' (see jsfiddle) and of any other menu items. How can I exclude them? Can I implement a general rule or do I have to exclude each with `exclude=pageid` in the PHP statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `child_of` parameter with the ID of the parent page as value, e.g.:

`wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=3');`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work in my case. It displays the sub items of the parent page as main menu items and the rest of the menu is gone.

Comment: Use the `wp_list_pages` function inside a nested `ul`, e.g.: `<ul id="menu"><li>My Page<ul><?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=3'); ?></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: thank you for that, I tried it but when I do that I have to change my whole CSS for the menu ... do you know if there is an easier solution?

Comment: Use a nav menu instead of `wp_list_pages`? http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Comment: I tried that too before using `wp_list_pages` but did not manage to create a dropdown menu for it. (sorry for that stupid questions, I'm new to Wordpress)

Comment: np! A nav menu is probably the way to go for you, nav menus can be rather easily customized with a so-called Walker class, check out: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/